# jQuery set value of time input tag

Tags: html, jquery, input

I'm attempting to set the value of an html input tag of type="time" via dynamic assignment using jQuery.

HTML Tag Code:

```
<input class="form-control" style="font-size: 1em;" type="time" name="time_start" id="time_start" value="" />
```

jQuery assignment code;

```
$('#time_start').val(dataIn.time_start);
// dataIn.time_start = "03:00:00 PM" (confirmed in console.log(dataIn))
```

I have this working for every other field in my form, except for some reason this particular one simply won't take. Is there something special about inputs of type "time" that is hosing this up?

Comment: Always check the console when debugging JS. You'll see a warning telling you why this doesn't work: `The specified value "03:00:00 PM" does not conform to the required format.  The format is "HH:mm", "HH:mm:ss" or "HH:mm:ss.SSS" where HH is 00-23, mm is 00-59, ss is 00-59, and SSS is 000-999.`

Comment: I'm confused as to how that doesn't conform since that value was initially created by  use of the browser's own built-in timepicker used when you set an input to type "time". So, how is this not an expected value if the browser (Chrome) was the source of entry?

Comment: I'm not challenging you on your point since that warning is definitely present in the debugging console as you'd stated. I just am failing to understand why a browser would provide an unacceptable value.

Comment: That issue is because time inputs, and date inputs, use the client's locale, not a single specific format. It's annoying as a developer, but makes sense for the UX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#time_value_format):

> The value of the time input is always in 24-hour format that includes leading zeros: hh:mm, regardless of the input format, which is likely to be selected based on the user's locale (or by the user agent). If the time includes seconds (see Using the step attribute), the format is always hh:mm:ss

`03:00:00 PM` is not a valid time. You need to specify it as `15:00:00`

```html
<input type="time" value="03:00:00 PM" />

<input type="time" value="15:00:00" />
```

Comment: I think the issue I just discovered is that you are right, in that it generates 24-hr formatting. However, it appears that the code that stored it to the database transposed it into what I posted here and hence broke the time input's expected format structure.
Thanks for the assist, folks!